# Bind value to ng-init using ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have one `select` field and one 'input' field,for both fields am getting data from database.
selected option will be checked defaultly based on db value.When I change dropdown option, `balance` field will be auto populated.
Now my problem is,`balance` field value is auto populating when I change dropdown. But by default balance field value is not auto populating for selected option.
Whats wrong here?
Html:

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-repeat="data in leaveDetails">

        <div>
            <label>Leave Type</label>
            <select type="text" ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName=data.LeavetypeId" ng-options="data.id as data.Name for data in leaveTypes" ng-change="leaveBalance(selectedName)"></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Availabe Leaves</label>
            <input type="text"  ng-init="balanceCount=data.Balance" ng-model="balanceCount">
        </div>

 </form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    var app=angular
                    .module('myApp', [])
                    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

                        $scope.init = function () {
                           $scope.loadEditLevDetails();
                        }

                        $scope.loadEditLevDetails = function (id) {
                            $scope.Id = { leaveRequestId: id };
                            var requestHeaders = {
                                'content-type': 'application/json'
                            }
                            var httpRequest = {
                                method: 'post',
                                url: "/user/details",
                                headers: requestHeaders,
                                data: $scope.Id
                            }
                            $http(httpRequest).then(function (response) {
                                $scope.leaveDetails = response.data;

                            })
                        }
                        $scope.leaveBalance = function (selectedvalue) {

                            $scope.leaveTypeId = { leaveTypeId: selectedvalue };
                            var requestHeaders = {
                                "content-type": 'application/json'
                            }
                            var httpRequest = {
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: '/user/balanceCount',
                                headers: requestHeaders,
                                data: $scope.leaveTypeId
                            }
                            $http(httpRequest).then(function (response) {
                                $scope.noOfValues = response.data;
                                $scope.balanceCount = $scope.noOfValues[0].balance_count;
                            })
                        }

                    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code to implement what you are trying to do!! Hope it would help!!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="test">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        angular.module('test',[])
                .controller('Main',function($scope)
                {
                    $scope.myModel = {};
                    $scope.options = [{opt:'1'},{opt:'2'},{opt:'3'}];
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Main">
{{'Select'}}
<select ng-model="myModel.options" ng-options="data.opt for data in options" ng-init="myModel.options=options[0]"></select>
{{myModel.options}}
</body>
</html>
```